# use fragment_container in replace transition

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to transit between 2 fragment from games.xml to levels.xml
its like angry bird game menu: 
games: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S7Ar.png
levels:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB8rP.jpg

games.java:

```
public class Games extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

public Games(){}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment f = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.s4:{
        f = new Levels();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if (f != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.lvl_container, f);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    } 
        }
```

level.java:

```
public class Levels extends Fragment {

public Levels(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.levels, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

levels.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lvl_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="@string/s4"/>

<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
    android:src="@drawable/lvlgray_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

games.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastgame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="@string/games"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/s4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lastgame"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/s4" />
```

the problem is when I click on imagebotton nothing happens (should go to levels), I think there is problem with these line

```
transaction.replace(R.id.lvl_container, f);
```

but I don't know what is it. Any ideas? 
I've already seen this (developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) but no help! What did I miss?
Is there any other way to transition between 2 fragments?
 Thank you

Comment: In which xml does id `lvl_container` belong to?

Comment: levels.xml (third line of code, is it wrong ?)

Comment: you do not have a listener set for imagebutton. Initialize it and set a listener for the same in onCreateView

Comment: thank u, but after there is error :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0008 (info.androidhive.slidingmenu:id/lvl_container) for fragment Levels{419490c8 #1 id=0x7f0a0008}

Comment: are both Fragments to be hosted by the same activity. If so you can have the container in the activity. Use interface as a callback to th activity. Then replace fragment. Fragment1 --> Activity --> Fragent2

Comment: also the container `lvl_container` does not belong to `games.xml`

Comment: yes, there are in the same activity,
it would be great if you help me with some link or example, about "having container in activity and using interface as callback" because i have no idea what are them? :) 
thank you very much

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: dear please post your `Activity` code & XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in onCreateView at Games.java:

```
 ImageButton im = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.s4);
 im.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This make refrence to your imagebutton and set onClickListener on it to call your onClick method.